# How to get Ipaddress of a particular user from listbox In c#?

Tags: c#, .net, listbox, ip-address

I have developed a chat application where in users who log in gets displayed in a listbox(they are visible to every user who is logged in). My question is I want to have a chat with Particular Person from the list of users displayed in listbox. **How can i get the ipaddress of that Particular user when double clicked on that user name?** i have used Socket for getting the Ipaddress and port number.Pls give me some suggestion.

Comment: before you retrieve a user and add to the listbox, you can add user ip to a List<string> value initialized with the number of first total ip addresses online. Then => myList[listBox1.SelectedIndex] = user ip

Comment: alternatively you can simply use a listView with two columns instead

Answer (score 0):

Do you store the IP-Adresses in the listbox, too? If you only want to show the user name or something similar in the listbox, you have to store the ip-addresses of the users somewhere else, propably a Dictionary, when you are adding the user to the ListBox:

```
var addresses = new Dictionary<string, string>();
addresses.Add("username", "127.0.0.1");
listBox.Add("username");
```

To get the ip-adress you could use:

```
var ipAdress = addresses[listBox.SelectedItem.Text]; // you should check for listbox.SelectedItem == null befor trying to access .Text!
```

(Code examples quick and dirty; not tested).

Comment: Hi,I am new to this website. i tried to send my code of server and client so that u can get clear idea what i want. but i am not able to send my code. so how how shall i send my code.

Comment: There is nothing like listbox.add()... so i have written listbox.items.add() is it okay?

Comment: Working with foreign code takes a lot of time and doesn't always help to find the intention of the code. You could post the really important parts of the code here in the text box and tell, what you are trying to achieve and at which point your problems occur.

Comment: Yes, listbox.items.add() is okay. My code was just an example to show you an idea; you have to modify it to fit your needs.